# How to print underscore variable in Python?

Tags: python

My code

```
import numpy as np
from pylab import plot,show
import scipy
import scipy.cluster
from scipy.cluster.vq import kmeans, vq

data_sillet = np.loadtxt('clustering_sillet.txt', delimiter=',')
data = data_sillet.astype(int)

print (type(data))

centroids, _ = scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans(data.astype(float), 3)
idx, _ = vq(data,centroids)
```

How to print the whole content of throwaway variable not just print (centroids)?

Comment: `_` is used as a garbage variable, something you don't care about, use a real name instead if this value matter

Comment: even so, what's wrong with `print ( _ )`? It's ugly, and as @PRMoureu said, if you care about a variable, don't call it `_`, but it's still a valid name.

Comment: `_` is still a valid identifier, so there's nothing that would forbid printing it using `print(_)`.

Comment: `_` is a valid variable name. It's just a convention that `_` is a 'throwaway' variable.

Comment: There is nothing special about the `_` variable. Its drawback is that when you read the code months later you don't remember what it means. Some people use `dummy` for garbage variables. This is more explicit.

Comment: In a script, `_` is just another variable. However, in the interactive interpreter it _is_ special: it's bound to the result of the last unassigned expression. Eg, if you do `1+2<Enter>` 3 gets printed, and if you then do `_<Enter>` 3 gets printed again, and if you then do `_+5<Enter>` 8 will be printed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of

```
centroids, _ = scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans(data.astype(float), 3)
```

use

```
centroids, i_want_this = scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans(data.astype(float), 3)
```

and then print `i_want_this`.

Comment: @DYZ - There are at least 3 good reasons for not do it: 1) not very descriptive name, 2) elusiveness, and 3) code maintaining.